# Error with Html.RouteLink in ASP.NET MVC RC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I was using  Html.RouteLink("LINKTEXT","RouteName",new RouteValueDictionary()) in  asp.net MVC beta without problem, today I upgrade to ASP.NET MVC RC and this does no create the link anymore. The route still works because I type in the browser and I go to the Page I want. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bug in RC. Workaround for now is to put your controller and action names in RouteLink.

For example:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(cat.Name, "Category", new { id = cat.id, controller = "Home", action = "Category" })%>
```

I also found one more issue with publishing web to shared hosting (mine is on iis6): "specific version" property of system.web.mvc reference in project has to be set to "false". Before it was "true" and I had one error in web.config regarding registration of sys.web.mvc assembly.